# Rotate wheel based on scrolling in a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I am trying to make a wheel rotate smoothly based on scrolling of a UIScrollView. I would want it to ease out when it almost stops scrolling the scrollview.

I tried much but failed so far, my current code is this:

```
#pragma mark - Scrollview delegate

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    NSLog(@"Offset: %@ Page: %i", NSStringFromCGPoint(scrollView.contentOffset), page);

    UIImageView* leftWheelImageView = (UIImageView*)[self.carImageView viewWithTag:10];

    // Calculate speed of scrolling and turn the wheels to it
    CGPoint currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    NSTimeInterval currentTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

    if(lastTime - currentTime > 0.1) {
        CGFloat distance = currentOffset.x - lastOffset.x;
        CGFloat scrollSpeedNotAbs = (distance * 10) / 1000; //in pixels per millisecond        
        CGFloat scrollSpeed = fabsf(scrollSpeedNotAbs);

        leftWheelImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(2*3.14*99));
        NSLog(@"Rotate wheel");
    }

    lastOffset = currentOffset;
    lastTime = currentTime;
}
```

Could anyone push me in the right direction :-)?

Comment: how about using `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` ?

Comment: well, i can get a speed in the didscroll method.. i was thinking to base my rotation on this. maybe if you have some snippets i could look what you mean exactly

Comment: There is a good library that I could suggest you, that I think would make your problem much easier I think.

Comment: Will the user be scrolling the scrollview or will it be automated? (ie predictable).

Comment: It needs to be able to do both

Comment: RDDRotationControlSurface is very close. https://github.com/rdsquared09/CircularScrollInertia

Answer (score 3):

You're setting your offset and time incorrectly; as it is, `lastOffset` and `lastTime` are being changed to `currentOffset` and `currentTime` every time you get the didScroll message. So your if statement will only be triggered if there's more than .1 seconds between each message. Since you said you wanted your scrolling to be smooth, it seems unlikely that this is what you were intending. Maybe move your assignments inside of your if statement? I'll see if I can find another method for you to use.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't  you  use the library for doing this ? I have done this using carousel library . Please refer following link 
https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel
this is easy and better to implement.

Comment: It would be better to use the native system inertia of UIScrollView.

Comment: Yes it is any time better to use native feature but i have just suggested one way to do it.